# Why is my Lenovo G500 laptop computer running slowly?

Tags: performance, cpu, lag

The one I’m currently using is a [Lenovo G500](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-g-series-laptops/lenovo-g500-notebook), Intel Core i7, 2.10 GHz, 8 GB RAM, 1 TB HDD, Windows 8.1 64-bit, AMD Radeon HD 8570M, Intel HD 4000.

The problem: it is slow. It lags even if Google Chrome and Notepad are open. According to my anti-virus, my device is free of malware and viruses.

Seeing that my computer should support heavy apps according to its specifications, these programmes still crash when opened and used for less than 5-10 minutes: After Effects, Photoshop, Visual Studio, HitFilm 3 Pro...

I also have a lot of free disk space and de-fragment disks frequently.

What may be some reasons of my computer behaving abnormally, being clean and formatted some months ago? Why is it this slow? Also, when a CD is inserted, the laptop makes annoying noise and slows down, sometimes until crash.

Comment: I actually *do* have one.

Comment: What happens when a cd is inserted? If you pull up the process explorer, what does your cpu ram and hdd activity look like?

Comment: The computer freezes and makes annoying noises whilst the performance decreases and CPU goes high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some ideas:

- Make sure your UEFI BIOS is at the latest version.
- Modern processors will slow down if they are running too hot.  If your system is very dusty, dust it out, otherwise have it serviced to see if the CPU is properly installed in the system.
- Check your hard disk - [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php), while it's primary purpose is reading the temperature sensors in your system, has a feature where it will display the SMART values of your hard drive and give you a friendly analysis online.
- Test your RAM by [downloading and burning a Memtest 86+ CD](http://www.memtest86.com/) or run the [built in Windows Memory Diagnostic](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/diagnosing-memory-problems-on-your-computer).